# Question regarding topics and headings for APA papers

Tags: apa

I am writing a trending topic paper for my Sociology class using APA format. I have 10 topics that I must talk about. How do I do this with the headings? I need the reader to know the different topics I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Given what you describe, I'd assume they are all top level headings, so each one would be bold and centred according to this:

http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/04/how-to-use-five-levels-of-heading-in-an-apa-style-paper.html?_ga=1.4127600.1910058635.1459817868

The introduction doesn't need a heading, it comes straight under the title.